# Prove that the number of edges is a multiple of 3 if each vertex has a degree that is either a multiple of 6 or 9

Tags: algorithms

So if G is an undirected graph where the degree of each vertex is a multiple of 6 or 9 i have to show that the number of edges is a multiple of 3.

where I am having trouble, I said that if the number of edges is equally divisible by 3 then the number of edges is a multiple of 3.

I feel like this isn't enough....and I feel like I should be looking more closely at how the vertices have to be a multiple of 6 or 9 but I don't know how to relate this.

Just looking for hints and tips in the right direction; i feel like it's blatantly obvious but I can't see it

Comment: To give a name to the result used below by BolzWeir, he used what is referred to as the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I used the equation given to get the number of edges (78 and 378). So from there I guess is where I got stuck. 

So instead of saying that "if the number of EDGES is equally divisible by 3 the number of edge is a multiple of 3", I should say that "Since the vertices each have a degree that is either a multiple of 6 or 9, each vertex is divisible by 3." So do I have to prove the part where BolzWeir said "this means their sum is divisible by 3"?

Comment: Do you have to prove that statement?  Only if you were speaking to a child perhaps.  I mean no offense in saying so, but the statement "a sum of numbers, each of which is divisible by $k$, will also be divisible by $k$" is an incredibly trivial statement which should be obvious without proof.  The only thing perhaps that should be mentioned, is that the $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't affect that since $3$ is coprime to $2$.

Comment: so based on the answers below, the two examples I did are not even necessary then

Comment: indeed.  Proof by example is invalid.  Disproof by counterexample is perfectly fine, but if you want to prove something, do not bother taking too much time looking at examples except to garner some intuition.  Afterall, you want to prove that the statement is true for *every* graph with those conditions.  If you show it is true only in specific cases, we don't yet know if it is true for the ones you haven't checked (and there are infinitely many such cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what is commonly referred to as the handshake lemma, 
$$m = \frac12 \sum_{v \in V} d(v)$$.  Let $a_1$ denote the number of vertices of degree 6, and let $a_2$ denote the number of vertices of degree 9.  Since, by the first theorem of graph theory, there cannot be an odd number of odd degree vertices, $a_2$ must be even, say $a_2 = 2k$ for some $k$.  Then, $$m = \frac12 \sum_{v \in V} d(v)=\frac{1}{2}(6a_1+9a_2)=\frac{1}{2}(6a_1+18k)=3(a_1+3k)$$, and so $m$ is indeed divisible by 3.

Comment: You could have avoided using "the first theorem" by noting since $m=\frac{1}{2}(a_1\cdot 6+a_2\cdot 9)$ that $2m=3(a_1\cdot 2 + a_2\cdot 3)$.  Therefore $3\mid 2m$.  By the definition of prime number, $3\mid 2$ or $3|m$.  Since $3\not\mid 2$ it must be that $3\mid m$.

Comment: thanks, that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 3):

For any given graph $G = (V,E)$, if $m$ denotes $|E|$, then:

$$m = \frac12 \sum_{v \in V} d(v)$$

As each vertex has a degree that is either a multiple of $6$ or a multiple of $9$, then each vertex's degree is divisible by $3$. This means that their sum is divisible by $3$, hence so is $m$.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I think more work needs to be done.  Sure, there sum will be divisible by 3, but the number of edges is not the same as the sum of the degrees.  As you've written it, the number of edges is the sum of the degrees divided by 2.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't matter. The sum of the degrees of vertices is always even, and its division by $2$ yields another integer. We don't need to worry about the $1/2$. The fact that $3$ divides the sum of degrees directly implies that $3$ divides $m$ as well.

Comment: Okay, I see how that makes sense.  Thank you.